# syslog question on rfc

Tags: linux, unix, logging, log4j, syslog

I would like to use syslog for logging from a remote application.
I have some questions though:
For example the RFC says:

```
If the originally formed message has a HOSTNAME field, then it
will contain the hostname as it knows itself.  If it does not
have a hostname, then it will contain its own IP address.
```

What does this mean? 
That the message from my application to the logging client library, if it contains some host name then it will be replaced?
Could you please give me an example?
I tried for instance:
`From localhost some data`
or
`From ahost@aa some data`
and these strings are stored in syslog server as they were send by my app to the syslog client lib.
Shouldn't they be different as a result of the above req??
I am using log4j for syslog client.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading the old [RFC 3164](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3164). That one's obsolete; the replacement is [RFC 5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424), which is much clearer on what goes in the `HOSTNAME` field:

> The HOSTNAME field identifies the
> machine that originally sent the
> syslog message.
>
> The HOSTNAME field SHOULD contain
> the hostname and the domain name of
> the originator in the format specified
> in STD 13 [[RFC1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034)].  This    format
> is called a Fully Qualified Domain
> Name (FQDN) in this    document.
>
> In practice, not all syslog
> applications are able to provide an
> FQDN.    As such, other values MAY
> also be present in HOSTNAME.  This
> document    makes provisions for using
> other values in such situations.  A
> syslog    application SHOULD provide
> the most specific available value
> first.    The order of preference for
> the contents of the HOSTNAME field is
> as    follows:
>
> 1. FQDN
> 2. Static IP address
> 3. hostname
> 4. Dynamic IP address
> 5. the NILVALUE

Comment: @larsman:I see in the syslog before e.g. `From localhost some data` the IP of the machine that runs my application.So this is what is expected and compliant with syslog? There is nothing to do with the actual application data (in this example `From localhost some data`)?

Comment: The RFC describes the hostname fields that Syslog implementations generate themselves. If you additionally put a hostname in a log message, then it will be preserved as-is: "Any syslog transport protocol MUST NOT deliberately alter the syslog message."

Comment: @larsman:I see. Do you know if syslog client implementations are usually fully compliant to RFC?

Comment: I wouldn't put my money on full compliance except if it's a very new implementation, but the RFCs do mostly codify existing practice, and violating the "no-edits" requirement seems like a stupid thing to do in any protocol. Test your implementation(s) to be sure.

Comment: @larsman:I apologise, I did not get your last comment.You are saying that RFCs usually are under modification so it is possible to make implementations deprecated?Or something else?

Comment: No, I mean these RFCs were written to provide a kind of standard for the many incompatible syslogs that existed before. Newer versions are likely written to the standard, but older ones weren't. They may have caught up, they may not have. Note that the latest RFC is from 2009.